Trying to figure out why my v-show has stopped working when I add a modal
I am attempting to learn Vue for the first time and I am building an application where I have a section where there are rows of data. Each row will be associated with lots of data about that element, to avoid loading all this data at one I have previously implemented a sort of "expandable row" using the v-show attribute. This was working great that on button press the row of information would expand and a call to my database would be made to retrieve the extra information about that specific row would be retrieved.
This was working until I attempted to add button that open modals for editing the information associated with that row or confirming deletion of that row. I was following the example on the Vue examples page about how to make a modal to get started (this example).
To hopefully explain this better I have the following structure to my components:
Row.vue
-> RowContent.vue
-> -> DeleteModal.vue
-> -> EditModal.vue
Row: The always visible information for each row including the button that will expand the row to make the RowContent visible
RowContent: The information that will be visible once the button is pressed in Row.vue and will contain the buttons to make the DeleteModal.vue and EditModal.vue visible.
DeleteModal.vue: The modal that will appear to ask the user if they are sure they want to delete the row
EditModal.vue: The modal that will appear so the user can edit the information in the row
Here is my code for the RowContent.vue and Row.vue:
Row.vue:
<script setup>
const isOpen=ref(false);
function expand(npc) {
        isOpen.value = !isOpen.value
        npcName.value = ref(npc.get('Name'));
        if(isOpen.value){
           getClass(npc);
           getType(npc);
           getRace(npc);
        }
    }
</script>
<template>
    <div class="RowBackground">
        <div class="alwaysShown">
            <h1>{{ npc.get('Name') }}</h1>
            <button @click="expand(npc)">Expand</button>
        </div>
        <RowContent class='drawer' :npcName='npcName' :npcClass='npcClass' :npcType='npcType' :race='race' :extra='extra' v-show='isOpen'></RowContent>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import RowContent from './RowContent.vue';
export default {
    props: {
        npc: Object,
    },
    components: {
        RowContent,
    },
</script>

RowContent:
<script setup>
import  DeleteModal from '../components/DeleteModal.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';
const showModal= ref(false);
</script>

<template>
    <div class="rowContainer">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Class: {{ npcClass }}</h3>
            <h3>Type: {{ npcType }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Race: {{ race }}</h3>
            <h3>Extra: {{ extra }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="editButton">Edit</button>
            <button class="deleteButton" @click="showModal=true">Delete</button>
        </div>
        
    </div>
     
    <DeleteModal :npcName="npcName" :show="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
    </DeleteModal>
   
</template>

DeleteModal:
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  show: Boolean,
});
</script>

<template>
  
    <div v-if="show" class="modal-mask">
      <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="deleteText">Delete {{ npcName }} permanently?</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="interactionButtons">
            <button>Confirm</button>
            <button @click="$emit('close')">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        npcName: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            isOpen: false,
        };
    },
}
</script>

I left out some of the styling and functions that are connecting to my backend because I did not think they were applicable. Please leave a comment and let me know if these will help in diagnosing the problem.

As you have defined a modal and used the same in the RowContent component, you just need to use the component inside the root node of template
RowContent.vue component
<template>
    <div class="rowContainer">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Class: {{ npcClass }}</h3>
            <h3>Type: {{ npcType }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Race: {{ race }}</h3>
            <h3>Extra: {{ extra }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="editButton">Edit</button>
            <button class="deleteButton" @click="showModal=true">Delete</button>
        </div>
     
      <DeleteModal :npcName="npcName" :show="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
      </DeleteModal>
   </div>
</template>

